# Javascript - hide one display element when another element is displayed on click

Tags: javascript

I have two "+" signs that toggle between open and close without any issues. I'd like to have it so when you click one to open and the other is already open, the one that was already open closes, and vice versa. I tried using document.getElementById() but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:display_affiliate('new_affiliate_info');" style="text-decoration: none;"><div id="add_aff" style="width:20px;color:red;font-size: 30px;">+</div></a>
<a href="javascript:display_author('new_author_info');" style="text-decoration: none;"><div id="add_auth" style="width:20px;color:red;font-size: 30px;">+</div></a>
```

Javascript

```
function display_author(id) {
    displayObject(id);
    if(document.getElementById('#new_affiliate_info').style.display != "none"){
        document.getElementById('#new_affiliate_info').style.display = "none";
    }
}

function display_affiliate(id) {
    displayObject(id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If a jQuery Solution is ok, I would use the `.toggle()` for this:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
  $("p").hide();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
  $("p").show();
});
```

or

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").toggle();
});
```